# Lenovo Ideapad 330 Ryzen 5 2500u Freeze issue Frequently

Tags: lenovo, freeze, ideapad

I have Just installed and setup Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on My Lenovo Ideapad 330 with AMD® Ryzen 5 2500u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8

Wifi was not working but I fixed that but
still my devices is getting freezed sometimes frequently.

No Errors etc, No Distortion, It Freezes, I can move the cursor but no buttons works..

Any Solutions?

PS: I am Newbie in Using Terminal, Don't Know much about linux commands.

Comment: Please can you show `dmesg | grep IOMMU`

Comment: I am Not aware how to do that

Comment: Open your terminal an cp&paste my command in. I want only to know if it is  a problem with I/O Memory Management Unit (I/O-MMU, or shortIOMMU.

Comment: `[    1.083849] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
[    1.088354] AMD-Vi: Found IOMMU at 0000:00:00.2 cap 0x40
[   16.130000] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <jroedel@suse.de>`

Comment: Sorry, I forget something `uname -a` please, but edit your question for that.

Comment: `Linux ViruxVX 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The 2 things, that I had in mind, are not relevant for your case.

Comment: Please Share it with someone who can help

Comment: My first idea is that using iommu is running in  GART mode(This is standart) but on some boards, it can make problems. My second was https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=90fcffd9cf5e7cc593169f529799f3e3c5437e75  but this should be fixed in your kernel version.

Comment: Can it be problem of Storage or Partitions, Because I have Installed it in a 32GB USB Flash Drive.

Also, My Ram is 8GB and I have set the Swap Disk to 4GB can it cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research and refusing to recompile the graphics stack manually I found you need to do 2 things to almost completely resolve this issue:  set a cstate restriction parameter for the kernel in `/etc/default/grub` and update the AMD graphics driver.

Open Terminal and open the file for editing with root privileges, for example (if you don't have mousepad you could use nano)

```
sudo mousepad /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` so that after your edit it includes the parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`, for example mine says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

You can keep other parameters, such as `quiet` and `splash` which may be there already.

save and exit the text editor, and run this command to update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now add a PPA for AMD graphics drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Now reboot.

This solution should work for other flavors of Linux (ie mint, mx, manjaro etc...) and other AMD powered machines experiencing this issue.

Do not use screen lock or system suspend and you will most likely never have a freeze again!

When I choose to stop being lazy and resolve system lock freeze issues I will update this response.

AMD has not released any official proprietary drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 as of this posting, when and if they do, I would recommend trying them.

Answer (score 1):

On my Lenevo Ideapad 330 with AMD Ryzen 5 processor, I also faced the same issue of hanging when system is working. Mostly it hangs when I open Firefox or Chrome browser and use it for some time.

I thought it might be an issue with the OS and later changed to Cent OS. I observed the same hanging issue in that OS as well.

Finally the issue resolved after I updated the bios from Lenevo's website. I think the bios (shipped by default when we purchase the laptop) has some issues.

I had a dual boot system with Windows and Linux. I used the Windows machine to update the bios as I didn't find any bios executable to download from Lenevo website for Linux.

Finally after updating bios using the Windows machine, it erased my grub but I was able to recover it with few commands by referring one help document. Later I didn't observe any issue of hanging in my Linux machine, So I believe updating the BIOS will resolve the hanging issue on this Lenevo model.