# Constant crashes on Ubuntu while watching videos in my web browser 'NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR'

Tags: firefox, amd-graphics, amdgpu, watchdog

I've been experiencing constant lockups ever since i started using Linux on my HP Envy x360.

**Hardware:** Ryzen 2500U with integrated Vega graphics, 12gb ram, 500gb Samsung nvme ssd

**Software:** Like i already mentioned, I'm experiencing this problem on every major Linux distro including but not limited to Arch Linux, Manjaro, Ubuntu and Ubuntu based systems like Pop_OS! I've tried different desktop environments, window managers and booth xorg and wayland to no avail.

These hard crashes usually occur while watching YouTube videos or playing somewhat graphic intensive games. They start with the current window becoming unresponsive and constantly lopping the last few seconds of audio. In most cases the mouse courser is still responding to my inputs butt that's about it. It always results in me having to restart the PC by longpressing the power button.

After restarting journalctl greets me with error messages that point booth to the window manager and the web browser

**Things I've already tried:**

-using a different desktop environment (Plasma, gnome, xfce etc) and their respective window managers

-using different display drivers (mesa, AMD driver)

-tried different web browsers

-everything mentioned above

-stress tested booth CPU and GPU

I'm getting really desperate right now. My experience with Linux has been awesome so far. I love it. But it's unfortunately unusable for me.

You can probably tell by reading the text above that booth my Linux and English linguistic skills are fairly limited. I'll appreciate every piece of advice.

Thanks in advance

(I will progressively update this post with more information below)

[Journalctl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSgY9.png)

Comment: Seems like a problem between Linux and that cpu.  Should google ubuntu freezes with your cpu to find more information before doing anything, but one link of many is  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200229/lenovo-ideapad-330-ryzen-5-2500u-freeze-issue-frequently